# What happened to moderator elections?

Tags: discussion

As far as I can tell, we haven't had a moderator election on SA since 2018.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: If your question was prompted by the current “wave of elections” across the network, those are either a consequence of the last wave of site graduations (after which _all_ moderator posts are up for election and beta mods have to run again) or filling the gaps left by moderators who stepped down. Considering how difficult it is been for some of them to find enough candidates, I am grateful that we here don’t have to go through the process at the moment.

Comment: yeah, I was just pinged for elections on 3 other SEs and was like "wait, why isn't SA having one".

Comment: Are you asking for the reason I suspect?  (As you’ve also commented on their actions)

Comment: I was asking for the reason I stated above.  Stephie's answer satisfied the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - and it’s simple:

On graduated sites, moderators are elected “for as long as they stay on board”. Provided that

- no moderator steps down
- isn’t removed by SE for inactivity or inappropriate behavior or
- the workload becomes too much for the existing team and new positions are opened up,

there’s no reason to hold an election.

If the circumstances change, we will contact CM, or vice versa, to schedule and hold an election. And the community will then be invited via meta post that there is one (or more) position open.